# Error System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported

Tags: scheduled-apex, callout

i have created a schedulable class which has to trigger a batch job. The run method for the batch class will get list of data to process from a webservice callout. Now, i got the exception below. Any suggestions please.

> System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.

```
global class scheduledDeltaBatchable implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    ID batchprocessid = BatchUpsertSAPCustomerMasterBPSync.run(SAPServices.GetSAPCustomerMasterBPSync('Delta'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to do it in the schedule class you will need to do it in an @future method:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2010/02/spring-10-saw-the-general-availability-of-one-of-my-favorite-new-features-of-the-platform-the-apex-schedulerwith-the-apex-s.html

or here on stack exchange:

[Scheduled Apex, Callouts and Running a Batch](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/scheduled-apex-callouts-and-running-a-batch)

> Why not just perform the callout in your Batch Apex start method? This
>   means you will always start the Batch Apex job from your Scheduled
>   apex job, but i think is on balance better than having to marshall
>   schedule jobs between @future jobs?

if you want to do it within the batch that is ran by the schedule you will need to implement the callout interface

```
global class scheduledDeltaBatchable implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts
```

> To use a callout in batch Apex, specify Database.AllowsCallouts in the
>   class definition

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: I have one scheduler apex, one flow, and one apex to make integration, the scheduler calls the flow, and the flow calls the apex of integration, in this case, should give an error of "Callout from scheduled Apex not supported"?