# getContent Issue on Scheduled Apex

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, callout, blob, getcontent

Recently, I've been developing a scheduled apex class to send a csv file to an email. I was using the getContent method from a report page to achieve this. I was doing fine when executing it in anonymous window. But upon scheduling it, I discovered that getContent is considered as callout and cannot be used in scheduled apex. Do someone knows any work around for this without querying the records and putting it in string and converting it to blob? We still want to use the report that was created if possible. Thanks!

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96536