# Schedule class doesnt work

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Im having problems creating a schedule job in SalesForce. i have this class:

```
global class dollarGetSC implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
         dollarGet.makeGetCallout();
 }
}
```

Im creating this for the job:

```
dollarGetSC sc = new dollarGetSC();
string cronExp = '0 0 22 * * ? *';  // 8:00am every day
string JobId = system.schedule('GETTING Dollar', cronExp, sc);
```

But it doesnt do nothing

If i call dollarGet.makeGetCallout(); works fine and i want to do it automatically through apex job but it doesn't work.

I get this error: Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7070j00000O5bWX, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you receiving any error? You are just scheduling your scheduler class at the specified time, and that it will be queued by Salesforce and will be executed whenever resources are available at/after that time.

Comment: No errors.
dollarGet.makeGetCallout(); updates a field if i call it from the developer console but it doesnt update if i do the job.

Comment: So has your job run? With the job scheduler code you have, you are scheduling the job to run at 10PM. Only when your scheduler runs, you will be able to see the updates. Are you able to verify if the job ran?

Comment: im testing changing the time of the job.

Comment: Well now i have this error: Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7070j00000O5bWX, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96536/error-system-calloutexception-callout-from-scheduled-apex-not-supported

Comment: It seems you are making a web service callout from your scheduled apex, which you cannot. Refer to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96538/54851) as how you can achieve it.